# How can I optimize google analytics in the gtmetrix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-analytics, gtmetrix

I'm optimizing my website using gtmetrix and I've got good grades. but it's still not perfect

Look at this image :

PageSpeed :

[pagespeed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smOby.png)

YSlow :

[yslow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ54J.png)

The picture shows that my value is not perfect because I installed the Google Analytics script on my website. if I delete it, I can get a perfect score. but here I need google analytics to analyze my website.

So how do I optimize the Google Analytics script on my website without removing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Host the JavaScript file locally but it is not recommended: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032389?hl=en

Comment: but what if there is a script change from google analytics? it seems like it won't automatically update on local

Comment: You can update it's contents with a caching script or manually. 
You can rely on the update frequency of the script to understand the need: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/changelog